# Why is our Chainlink node not catching any OracleRequest events from our Arbitrum Operator? Requests are never fulfilled / v2 jobs never executed

Tags: chainlink

We're trying to get our Chainlink AnyAPI stack to work with an Arbitrum Chainlink node. The same stack is being used on Ethereum, Polygon and Avalanche without issue.

Chainlink AnyAPI empowers some of the use cases of DSLA Protocol, a middleware for adding consumer protection capabilities to any monitorable marketplace (e.g. OpenSea) using peer-to-peer service level agreements (SLA).

### Request Lifecycle

Here are the different steps involved in verifying that a SLA contract has been respected, using Chainlink:

1. A user calls the verification function on the Messenger smart contract that implements Chainlink.
2. The `Messenger` smart contract sends the request the `PreCoordinator` smart contract .
3. The `PreCoordinator` forwards the request to the Oracles defined in a Service Agreement (proxy of Oracles).
4. Upon receiving LINK, each Oracle sends the request to the Chainlink node, by emitting an `OracleRequest` event with the id of the job to be executed.
5. The Chainlink node captures such event, and executes the corresponding job.
6. Once the job is executed, the Chainlink node calls the `fulfillOracleRequest2` function to return the result from the external adapter to the PreCoordinator.
7. The PreCoordinator takes the mean of all Oracle results and ultimately registers the SLI in the messenger.
8. The SLA is verified (real vs goal) by comparing the SLI (real) and the SLO (goal).

### Fulfillment Issue

It appears our node doesn't pick the OracleRequest event of our PreCoordinator v0.6 / Operator v0.7 setup.

The request is never fulfilled so we've been wondering if our job id syntax is correct in the PreCoordinator service agreements (among other things) and if, perhaps, there's a peculiar configuration to apply to the node / v2 job specs.

### AnyAPI Stack

- PreCoordinator.sol: a proxy for using multiple Chainlink oracles using service agreements
- v0.6 Chainlink contracts:

```
import '@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/ChainlinkClient.sol';
import '@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/LinkTokenReceiver.sol';
import '@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/Median.sol';
import '@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/Ownable.sol';
import '@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/vendor/SafeMathChainlink.sol';
```

- v0.7 `Operator.sol`* contract

- Migrated from the v0.6 Oracle.sol smart contract, in an attempt to solve this issue.

- An v1.9.0 Arbitrum Chainlink node with a v2 job specification:

```
type = "directrequest"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "StakingParametricRequest"
forwardingAllowed = false
maxTaskDuration = "0s"
contractAddress = "0x6Dc1147ca16C020579642D90042CeA252474fD67"
minContractPaymentLinkJuels = "0"
observationSource = """
    decode_log   [type=ethabidecodelog
                  abi="OracleRequest(bytes32 indexed specId, address requester, bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddr, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 cancelExpiration, uint256 dataVersion, bytes data)"
                  data="$(jobRun.logData)"
                  topics="$(jobRun.logTopics)"]

    decode_cbor  [type=cborparse data="$(decode_log.data)"]
    fetch        [type=bridge name="staking-parametric" requestData="{\\"id\\": $(jobSpec.externalJobID), \\"data\\": { \\"sla_monitoring_start\\": $(decode_cbor.sla_monitoring_start), \\"sla_monitoring_end\\": $(decode_cbor.sla_monitoring_end), \\"sla_address\\": $(decode_cbor.sla_address), \\"network_name\\": $(decode_cbor.network_name)}}"]
    parse        [type=jsonparse path="data,result" data="$(fetch)"]
    encode_large [type="ethabiencode"
                abi="(bytes32 requestId, bytes _data)"
                data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"_data\\": $(parse)}"
                ]
    encode_tx    [type=ethabiencode
                  abi="fulfillOracleRequest2(bytes32 requestId, uint256 payment, address callbackAddress, bytes4 callbackFunctionId, uint256 expiration, bytes calldata data)"
                  data="{\\"requestId\\": $(decode_log.requestId), \\"payment\\": $(decode_log.payment), \\"callbackAddress\\": $(decode_log.callbackAddr), \\"callbackFunctionId\\": $(decode_log.callbackFunctionId), \\"expiration\\": $(decode_log.cancelExpiration), \\"data\\": $(encode_large)}"
                 ]
    submit_tx    [type=ethtx to="0x6Dc1147ca16C020579642D90042CeA252474fD67" data="$(encode_tx)"]

    decode_log -> decode_cbor -> fetch -> parse -> encode_large -> encode_tx -> submit_tx
"""
```

- The following environment variables:

```
ETH_CHAIN_ID: "42161"
LINK_CONTRACT_ADDRESS: "0xf97f4df75117a78c1A5a0DBb814Af92458539FB4"
ETH_URL: "wss://arbitrum-mainnet.s.chainbase.online/v1/[redacted]"
ETH_SECONDARY_URLS: "https://morning-dimensional-morning.arbitrum-mainnet.quiknode.pro/[redacted]/"
```

Has anybody experienced a similar issue?

Thanks a tons for your help!
Wilhem

Answer (score 1):

After a quick glance I can say that the `encode_tx` task has a wrong `abi` value. `fulfillOracleRequest2` must have `data` as `bytes` not `bytes32`.

From: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/contracts/src/v0.7/Operator.sol#L208

Comment: Thanks, good catch! We're trying out different v2 job specs right now, I've edited my post to reflect the one that's currently being validated. It's now using `fulfillOracleRequest` instead of `fulfillOracleRequest2`, will let you know how it goes.